# Error in parsing json data while creating a user login using flutter and php

Tags: php, json, flutter

I am trying to create a user login using flutter and backend in php. But while pursing the json data flutter shows error: "type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<int, dynamic>'". Please help me out. I am stuck here for 2 days.
My flutter code is:

```
   Future<Login> userLogin(String email, String password) async {
   String body = '{"email":"' + email + '", "password":"' + password + '"}';

  final http.Response response = await http.post(
  'My php page',
  headers: <String, String>{
   'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
 body: body,
 );

   if (response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 200) {
     return Login.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
   } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to login.');
   }
}

class Login {
   final int usrid;
   //final String usrname;
   final int status;

   Login({this.usrid, this.status});

   factory Login.fromJson(Map<int, dynamic> json) {
   return Login(usrid: json['usrid'], status: json['type']);
}
}

 class TextControl extends StatefulWidget {
  TextControl({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _TextControl();
   }
 }

 class _TextControl extends State<TextControl> {
   final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
   final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
   final TextEditingController _controller2 = TextEditingController();

 // get user id from disk
 void _getUserid() async {
   final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // if already logged in, redirect to another page
    if (prefs.getInt('userid') > 0) {
    Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TextInput()),
    );
    } else {}
 }

 @override
   void dispose() {
   // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
   _controller.dispose();
   _controller2.dispose();
   super.dispose(); 
 }
 // save user id to disk
 void _loadUserid(final int userid) async {
   final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   prefs.setInt('userid', userid);
 }

 Future<Login> _futureLogin;
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   _getUserid();
   return Form(
   key: _formKey,
   child: (_futureLogin == null)
      ? Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter valid email.';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _controller2,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
              obscureText: true,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter password.';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.purple[400],
                textColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    setState(() {
                      _futureLogin =
                          userLogin(_controller.text, _controller2.text);
                    });
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Login'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      : FutureBuilder<Login>(
          future: _futureLogin,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              //return Text(snapshot.data.usrname);
              if (snapshot.data.status == 1) {
                _loadUserid(snapshot.data.usrid);
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TextInput()),
                );
              } else {
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(content: Text('Invalid login credentials.')));
              }
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
     );
     }

    }
```

And my php code is:

```
  $jsonText = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $json = json_decode($jsonText);

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

  $email = $json->email;
  $password = $json->password;
  $dbConn = dbConn();
  if($email && $password){
   $status = array('type'=>'','usrid'=>'');
   
   $LogSql=dbQuery($dbConn,"select id,name from `users` where `email`='".tep_db_input($email)."' and 
   `pass`='".$password."'");

        if(dbNumRows($LogSql)>0)
        {
            $RsSql = dbFetchObject($LogSql);
            $status['type']=1;
            $status['usrid']=$RsSql->id;
        }
        else
        {
            $status['type']=2;
            $status['usrid']=0;
        }

     print (json_encode($status));
     exit;
  }
  }
```

I am not understanding where the problem lies. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This error is gone after changing this to Map<String, dynamic>. But now a new error has appeared. If login is valid, an error appears: **"type _OneByteString is not a subtype of type int"**. Can you help me about why the error is appearing? Is it because I used **_loadUserid(snapshot.data.usrid)** to store the usrid to disk and set the type of the argument of the function to int? If yes, how do I save the usrid to disk becaue if the login is **valid** the usrid has to be set in the localstorage to make sure that user is already logged in. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code:

```
class Login {
   final int usrid;
   //final String usrname;
   final int status;

   Login({this.usrid, this.status});

   factory Login.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   return Login(usrid: json['usrid'], status: json['type']);
}
```

I think you are using `Map<int,dynamic>` and you want `Map<String, dynamic>`

Comment: Thanks for answering. The return values of json are all of type int. In spite of that I will use Map<String, dynamic>?

Comment: Thanks. This error is gone after changing this to Map<String, dynamic>. But now a new error has appeared. If login is valid, an error appears: "type _OneByteString is not a subtype of type int". Can you help me about why the error is appearing? Is it because I used **_loadUserid(snapshot.data.usrid)** to store the usrid to disk and set the type of the argument in the function to int? Please help.

Comment: snapshot.data.usrid is returns a string, and your method variable in int, so please do change accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, it's works. But it works when valid email and password is entered. If wrong email or password is given it gives error: type '_Smi' is not a subtype of type 'String'. Can't understand why. I am returing $status['type'] = '2' if login is invalid and $status['type'] = '1' if login is valid. Both are Strings. So why error occurs for invalid login? I have no idea. Please help!!

Comment: you can use a dynamic type variable